# How to Export Tally Data programmatically to CSV or Excel format

Tags: python, etl, pentaho, tally

I am trying to export data from Tally ERP9 using Python/Pentaho. Is there any way to connect to Tally ERP9 and export the data programmatically or via Pentaho?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Tally enables a http server, usually at port 9000. You can enable the HTTP server by pressing on F12-Configuration and clicking on 'yes' to enable Tally as a Client and Server.

If you now hit the URL http://localhost:9000 (or the port you set), you will see a response

```
TALLY ERP9 Server is running
```

You can now interact with the server via SOAP requests in XML format.

Refer to the Tally Integration details on help.tallysolutions.com for more details on how to make these SOAP requests.